# ASP.NET MVC4 mobile site displays correctly on local host not deployment server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, opera-mobile

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 site with mobile content.  When I deploy this on my local development machine, the mobile content is what I see in Opera Mobile when I go to localhost/mysite.  However, when I deploy this to my actual server, I see the desktop version on Opera Mobile.  I get the same desktop view when visiting the site on my Windows Phone.

I am assuming this is not a DisplayModeProvider issue as site works as expected on local host.  What should I be looking at?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your specific mobile views were deployed correctly?

Comment: I see the mobile views in their respective folders.  Is there another way to check this?  To deploy, I have tried using FileZilla to copy from my localhost (which works correctly).  I also tried publishing via Visual Studio.  In both cases, I get same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed .NET 4.5 RC fixed this problem.   I may have missed this somewhere in the documentation that ASP.NET MVC4 requires .NET 4.5.