# MVC 4 Mobile Display Mode Doesn't work after deployment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 mobile display mode.

It works perfectly locally - if I use a user agent switcher it switches to mobile as expected.

As soon as I deploy it to my live IIS server it doesn't ever go to the mobile view on a phone or with user agent switched.

The server has .Net 4.5 on it and the site is using .Net 4 integrated for its app pool. (So doesn't seem to be this [ASP.NET MVC4 mobile site displays correctly on local host not deployment server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170117/asp-net-mvc4-mobile-site-displays-correctly-on-local-host-not-deployment-server))

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else has this issue make sure you check that the view is being deployed to the live server. It wasn't marked as Content for me so wasn't being dployed. I guess because I copied it into the project.

Anyway simple error on my part.